# ReportBuilder/SSRS - How to make a report with multiple tables, same dataset and just display data from each row and repeat headers?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

Probably I am not defining correctly my problem, but a customer asked for a report that uses only 1 data set and wants three tables, one of 9 columns, the second with 6 rows and a third table with a simple row.

Now each table needs to be display one row at a time and then repeat headers with the subsequent data, all matching like I was using a single row Tablix.

Basically, I have been playing the Grouping, Page Breaks options, List and Rectangle and haven't got the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. add tablix control
2. configure with dataset
3. define structure of the first table and set the visibility of rows and columsn based on your data
4. right click on row header of the first table and select row group --> group properties. set the grouping expression to a field that identifies each row uniquely
5. repeat 3-4 for second and third tables
6. repeaet the headers for each row - right click on row header of each table and select tablix props. go to row headers and enable the repeat header rows on each apge option.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but can you elaborate on steps, please? I followed but only manage to have the tables on each individual pages, so three pages and all data within each table.